# How does tablesort.js create the sort indicator arrows

Tags: javascript, css

I recently found the [tablesort.js](http://tristen.ca/tablesort/demo/) component, which allows to make the rows of a plain HTML table sortable. Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2TTxT/) for a small example.

I'm trying to understand how the sort-indicators (up/down arrows) in the table header are created.

The CSS used by tablesort.js is very minimal and does not contain any (background-) images. Also looking at the javascript code and using the browser's developer tools did not help me to understand how the indicators are created.

Can someone please explain how these indicators are created?

---

Here is the CSS used by tablesort.js:

```
th.sort-header {
  cursor:pointer;
  }
th.sort-header::-moz-selection,
th.sort-header::selection {
  background:transparent;
  }
table th.sort-header:after {
  content:'';
  float:right;
  margin-top:7px;
  border-width:0 4px 4px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#404040 transparent;
  visibility:hidden;
  }
table th.sort-header:hover:after {
  visibility:visible;
  }
table th.sort-up:after,
table th.sort-down:after,
table th.sort-down:hover:after {
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:0.4;
  }
table th.sort-up:after {
  border-bottom:none;
  border-width:4px 4px 0;
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating triangles using borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960497/creating-triangles-using-borders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using pseudo elements:

```
table th.sort-header:hover:after {
    visibility: visible;
}
table th.sort-header:after {
    content: '';
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border-width: 0 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #404040 transparent;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

They then toggle a class to change the border-width style which changes the arrow.

Edit: To clarify, the border-width style is what makes the arrow shape.